# how to tag an equation within an itemize - using amsart

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, indentation, itemize

I'm doing the following thing

```
\documentclass[leqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
Example.
\begin{itemize}
\item Such and so
\item the following holds
   \begin{align}
       x - 2
   \end{align}
       always.
\item whatever else
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Since I number my equations on the left, what I don't like about this is that the equation number is closer to the margin than the itemize bullets, while I would like it to be the other way around. Is there a way to do that? Maybe I should create a box or minipage with tikz (or something similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post complete documents which reproduce the problem.

With the standard classes the bullets are to the left of the number:

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


aaa

\begin{itemize}
\item Such and so
\item the following holds
   \begin{align}
       x - 2
   \end{align}
       always.
\item whatever else
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

`amsclass` has an apparently explicit design to produce

[image]

Which you can over-rule by

```
\documentclass[leqno]{amsart}
\def\fullwidthdisplay{}%\displayindent\z@ \displaywidth\columnwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


aaa

\begin{itemize}
\item Such and so
\item the following holds
   \begin{align}
       x - 2
   \end{align}
       always.
\item whatever else
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I must admit I haven't checked with the standard class, I just didn't think it'd make a difference. I am using amsart.

Comment: @carmelodevisu It _always_ makes a difference, and even when it doesn't it saves the person trying to help from having to type `\documentclass`... and guess the needed packages.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! could you say a few words about the line you comment out? What is the bit from \displayindent onwards?

Comment: amsart executes `\fullwidthdisplay` at the start of every display which over-rides the width it would have (which is narrower in a list) and forces it to be `\columnwidth` wide always. I suspect this is because in the journal page size using two column, an indented list is too narrow for a useful math display. the change just redefines the command to do nothing so you get the default display width.

Comment: oh I see, so the second bit you commented out is just what would have gone inside \fulldisplaywidth{}, correct?

Comment: @carmelodevisu yes I copied that line from the source of `amsart` then commented out almost all of it.

Comment: thanks very much, that was very helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: @carmelodevisu sorry I meant to uncomment the line again before posting, I see why you were confused, I'll edit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- `amsart` two-column??? surely you're thinking of something else.  however, the width of the text *is* the basis of this stylistic decision; when there are multiple list levels, each one is indented further, and numbered equations would then have labels indented to different distances from the left margin, which could get confusing; so the decision was made to keep then all aligned at the left.  also, `leqno` is the `amsart` default, which made a decision imperative.