# Change horizontal alignment of equation tags

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, lists, indentation

By default, equation numbering seems to left align.  However, I would like instead to indent the equation number just slightly.  The motivation for this is to align the equation number with the body of text surrounding it (which itself is indented because it appears in a list).  For example, see the following:

[image: eqnnumblist]

In this example, I would instead like to align the (A.1) tag with the text instead of with the left margin.

How do I do this?

**EDIT**:  As requested, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

This is text before the list.
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item This is an item in a list, and this is an equation in the list:
\begin{equation}
x^2+3x-1=3.
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
This is text after the list.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

It's definitely worth noting that the problem is solved by changing the document class from `amsart` to `article` (though this is not an option for my document).

Comment: In standard documents with the `leqno` option the label _is_ alignment with the item text.  Please post a minimal document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: this is covered here: [how to tag an equation within an itemize - using amsart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119507/579).  it is ams style to have all equation numbers aligned to the left margin, so they don't "jump around"; it is considered more difficult to spot a particular number if the alignment varies widely.