# Equation tag alignment inside enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, indentation, enumerate, tags

I am trying to align my tag to left margin. I've seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119489/how-to-tag-an-equation-within-an-itemize-using-amsart), but it did not help me muh as I don't want to change the class to ams. I have a solution (the code below), but I wonder if there is a better, wiser way to achieve the same. I would be happy if all displayed-math environments ignored all the indents added by enumerate or itemize.

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{Ad} (a).]
\item
Suppose $n=\sum_{p\in\bar{P}(n)}F_p$. We will show that\\
\hspace*{-1.4cm}\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{equation}\bar{P}(n)=P\left(n-F_{p_n}\right)\cup\{p_n\},\label{fpn}
\end{equation}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Preferable here use `\hspace*{-\leftmargin}` rather then `\hspace*{-1.4cm}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you find the following approach useful:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage{calc,changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{textwide}% environment for display math in lists
    {\begin{adjustwidth}{-\leftmargin-\labelwidth+\labelsep+\itemindent}{}%
     \vspace{-1em}
    }{\end{adjustwidth}}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}[{Ad} (a).]
\item
Suppose $n=\sum_{p\in\bar{P}(n)}F_p$. We will show that
    \begin{textwide}
\begin{equation}\bar{P}(n)=P\left(n-F_{p_n}\right)\cup\{p_n\},\label{fpn}
\end{equation}
    \end{textwide}
\lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

It gives the following result:

[image]