# Thmbox with numbered equation

Tags: tags, thmbox

I would like to use the thmbox package but when the environment contains an equation (align etc.) with a tag then the tag is displayed out of the body, see the example[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=TheoremL,thmbox={L,bodystyle={\vspace{1mm}\slshape\noindent}}]{thml}
\declaretheorem[name=TheoremM,thmbox={M,bodystyle={\vspace{1mm}\slshape\noindent}}]{thmm}
\declaretheorem[name=TheoremS,thmbox={S,bodystyle={\vspace{1mm}\slshape\noindent}}]{thms}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{thm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
{\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{head}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy} 

\begin{thm}
 Theorem with an equation
   \begin{equation}
    formula
   \end{equation}
 and align
   \begin{align}
    formula\\
    formula
   \end{align}
\end{thm}

 \begin{thml}
 Theorem with an equation
   \begin{equation}
    formula
   \end{equation}
 and align
   \begin{align}
    formula\\
    formula
   \end{align}
\end{thml}

 \begin{thmm}
 Theorem with an equation
   \begin{equation}
    formula
   \end{equation}
 and align
   \begin{align}
    formula\\
    formula
   \end{align}
\end{thmm}

 \begin{thms}
 Theorem with an equation
   \begin{equation}
    formula
   \end{equation}
 and align
   \begin{align}
    formula\\
    formula
   \end{align}
\end{thms}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me how to move the tag to the right position?

Answer (score 1):

As in [how to tag an equation within an itemize - using amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119489/how-to-tag-an-equation-within-an-itemize-using-amsart) it suffices to add

```
\def\fullwidthdisplay{}%\displayindent\z@ \displaywidth\columnwidth}
```